# java regex to replace any single character with space

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove any single character (including single characters at the beginning or end of string). 
For example,

```
String s = "I am testing regex. This'll print results for A B c d ^ * ( ) { } [ ] done .";
System.out.println(s);
```

should print:

```
am testing regex. This'll print results for           done
```

---

I tried:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\s+.(?=\\s))", " ");
```

which gives me:

```
I am testing regex. This'll print results for           done .
```

I want to remove the beginning and ending single characters as well in the same regular expression.

Comment: Any *non-whitespace* char? Try [`.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)\\S(?!\\S)", " ")`](https://regex101.com/r/8mh9V8/1), and perhaps, use `trim()` on the result.

Comment: Any character (including whitespace characters like "\t").

Comment: Either `.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)[^ ](?!\\S)", " ")` or `.replaceAll("(?s)(?<!\\S).(?!\\S)", " ")` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
.replaceAll("(?s)(?<!\\S).(?!\\S)", " ")
```

or

```
.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)[^ ](?!\\S)", " ")
```

and, perhaps, use `trim()` on the result. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8mh9V8/2).

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL embedded flag option (so that `.` could match any character including line break symbols)
- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind requiring either start of string or a whitespace before the current location
- `.` - (the *consuming* part) any single char (if it must be anything but space, use `[^ ]`)
- `(?!\S)` -  a negative lookahead that requires either the end of string or a whitespace immediately to the right of the current location.

Note that you may further adjust the *consuming* part as needed. If you only need to match non-whitespace chars, replace `.` with `\S`.